# Unable to set 4K resolution on Samsung S32R75 with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, display-resolution

I just bought this 4K monitor, but the highest available resolution is 1920x1080.

This is the output of the `xrandr` command:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 697mm x 392mm
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I read that someone got 4K on a different monitor by enabling Wayland and using a Wayland session. Alas, this did not work for me.

Comment: we will need some system info such as what GPU you are using and what drivers are installed as well as what kernel your system is using

Comment: another thing to consider is the cable type 4k will require hdmi 2.0 cable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I'm afraid, I was too quick to accuse the operating system.

*My graphics card is an Intel HD 2500, and according to [this page](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000023781/graphics.html) its maximum resolution seems to be 2560x1600@60 for DisplayPort, 1920x1080@60 for HDMI.
So I need to upgrade my graphics card (or at the very least get a DP cable).*

Edited to add: In fact, 4k resolution works through DisplayPort even with that graphics card. It's not the HDMI cable at fault, I suppose, since it's the one that came with the monitor.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly it's that your HDMI doesn't support 4K?

Comment: I had a similar problem - I had a 4K HDMI 2 cable - but the problem appears to be that I also had a dongle from Dell (DA200) that converted USB-C to HDMI - and that appears to be only HDMI 1.4.

Comment: @icc97 Bingo, I think you nailed it! The output from my graphics card is DisplayPort, so I have a dongle that converts DisplayPort to HDMI - and that may be the real problem here.